# Pubnub null reference exception in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, pubnub, leaderboard

I am trying to get my leaderboard working in unity using pubnub. I tried to follow and alter [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b42bhUfcLxc&t=270s) but when I run it in unity, nothing shows up:
[image]

In my code, the only thing that's different from the tutorial is the publish key and subscribe key, where I set to my own one.

this is the screenshot of the keys:[image]

this is the screenshot of the storage and playback setting: [image]
this is the screenshot of the pubnub function setting, it says "it's automatically set to on when a module is running":[image]

this is the screenshot of the only module in the app:[image]

this is my code, nothing is print to the console when I tried to set usernames and scores(see comment below):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using PubNubAPI;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using SimpleJSON;

public class MyClass
{
    public string username;
    public string score;
    public string refresh;
}

public class leaderboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PubNub pubnub;
    public Text Line1;
    public Text Line2;
    public Text Line3;
    public Text Line4;
    public Text Line5;
    public Text Score1;
    public Text Score2;
    public Text Score3;
    public Text Score4;
    public Text Score5;

    public Button SubmitButton;
    public InputField FieldUsername;
    public InputField FieldScore;
    //public static leaderboard instance;
    //public Object[] tiles = {}
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = SubmitButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);

        // Use this for initialization
        PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
        pnConfiguration.PublishKey = "pub-c-450b-redacted";
        pnConfiguration.SubscribeKey = "sub-c-03aa-redacted";

        pnConfiguration.LogVerbosity = PNLogVerbosity.BODY;
        pnConfiguration.UUID = Random.Range(0f, 999999f).ToString();

        pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
        Debug.Log(pnConfiguration.UUID);

        MyClass fireRefreshObject = new MyClass();
        fireRefreshObject.refresh = "new user refresh";
        string firerefreshobject = JsonUtility.ToJson(fireRefreshObject);
        pubnub.Fire() // This will trigger the leaderboard to refresh so it will display for a new user. 
            .Channel("submit_score")
            .Message(firerefreshobject)
            .Async((result, status) =>
            {
                if (status.Error)
                {
                    Debug.Log(status.Error);
                    Debug.Log(status.ErrorData.Info);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log(string.Format("Fire Timetoken: {0}", result.Timetoken));
                }
            });

        pubnub.SubscribeCallback += (sender, e) =>
        {
            SubscribeEventEventArgs mea = e as SubscribeEventEventArgs;
            if (mea.Status != null)
            {
            }
            if (mea.MessageResult != null)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> msg = mea.MessageResult.Payload as Dictionary<string, object>;

                string[] strArr = msg["username"] as string[];
                string[] strScores = msg["score"] as string[];

                int usernamevar = 1;
                //setting usernames, nothing is printed to the console
                foreach (string username in strArr)
                {
                    string usernameobject = "Line" + usernamevar;
                    GameObject.Find(usernameobject).GetComponent<Text>().text = usernamevar.ToString() + ". " + username.ToString();
                    usernamevar++;
                    Debug.Log(username);
                }

                //setting scores, nothing is printed to the console
                int scorevar = 1;
                foreach (string score in strScores)
                {
                    string scoreobject = "Score" + scorevar;
                    GameObject.Find(scoreobject).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
                    scorevar++;
                    Debug.Log(score);
                }
            }
            if (mea.PresenceEventResult != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("In Example, SusbcribeCallback in presence" + mea.PresenceEventResult.Channel + mea.PresenceEventResult.Occupancy + mea.PresenceEventResult.Event);
            }
        };
        pubnub.Subscribe()
            .Channels(new List<string>() {
                "leaderboard_scores"
            })
            .WithPresence()
            .Execute();
        //TaskOnClick();
    }

    public void TaskOnClick()
    {
        var usernametext = FieldUsername.text;// this would be set somewhere else in the code
            var scoretext = FieldScore.text;
            MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
            myObject.username = FieldUsername.text;
            myObject.score = FieldScore.text;
            string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(myObject);

            pubnub.Publish()
                .Channel("submit_score")
                .Message(json)
                .Async((result, status) =>
                {
                    if (!status.Error)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(string.Format("Publish Timetoken: {0}", result.Timetoken));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log(status.Error);
                        Debug.Log(status.ErrorData.Info);
                    }
                });
            //Output this to console when the Button is clicked
            Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
        }
    


}
```

If there are any other things you would need to know, please let me know.
Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you publishing any messages? If so, from where? Can you capture SDK logs and share them? see https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/unity/troubleshooting

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did you contact PubNub support? Just want to know if you still need attention on this issue.